# Django admin URL visible redirect

Tags: python, django, url

I started a new Django project today and something is bothering me.

When I go to the Django admin login form, I'm redirected from     `mysite.com/admin/` to `mysite.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/`.

The only difference from this install and the previous I made some time ago is the Django version changing from 1.6 to 1.7. After some research I still don't have any clue on how to get back to a "clean" URL displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admin redirection strategy [has changed in Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#admin-login-redirection-strategy). In other words, if you visit admin page other than `/admin/login/` it'll use http redirect and append `next=...` to the querystring. I don't think it's possible to change it to the way it worked pre-1.7 right now.

Comment: I've seen it just now, it's a pity since the "Django way" encourages clean URL displaying...
I'll look for a tricky solution anyway, thanks for your precisions.

Comment: I have to ask, why do you care so much how your _admin_ url looks like? I'm sure only couple of people are going to have access to it anyway.

Comment: It's just because I'm a little bit peeky and I liked the "clean URL" way of pre-1.7 !